# MemoryError when querying database from Process

Tags: process, python-3.5, peewee

I am trying to create a program with 3 processes that read from the same database. The code was working before I started introducing processes.

I am getting MemoryError when performing a `select()` from PeeWee, I suspect there is something wrong with sharing of resources. Minimal example:

**models.py**

```py
from playhouse.pool import PooledSqliteExtDatabase

file_scanner_database = PooledSqliteExtDatabase(
    None,
    max_connections=32,
)

class FileModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = file_scanner_database
```

**main.py**

```py
from file_scanner import FileScanner
from models import file_scanner_database
from models import FileModel
from multiprocessing import Process

def create_scanner_agent(data):
    scanner = FileScanner(data)
    scanner.start_scanner()

shared_info = {'db_location': '/absolute/path/to/database'}

file_scanner_database.init(shared_info['db_location'])
file_scanner_database.connect()
file_scanner_database.create_tables([FileModel], safe=True)

new_process = Process(
    target=create_scanner_agent,
    args=(shared_info,)
)
new_process.daemon = True
new_process.start()

try:
    new_process.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

new_process.terminate()
```

**file_scanner.py**

```py
from models import file_scanner_database
from models import FileModel

class FileScanner:
    def __init__(self, data):
        for k, v in data.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

        file_scanner_database.init(self.db_location)
        file_scanner_database.connect()

    def start_scanner(self):
        while True:
            # THIS IS WHERE THE PROGRAM CRASHES
            for row in FileModel.select():
                ...
```

Comment: If I use `Thread` instead it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access memory across a fork? Or some such craziness? I think the answer is that you're doing it wrong homie. Try opening your DB connection after the fork.

Comment: I am trying to access the same Sqlite file across the fork, but *not* using the same DB connection. The first connection serves to create tables when needed, and the subprocesses then initialize their own connections and use the same DB. Closing the connection before forking makes no difference, so there is some resource that stays open. I realized that to make it work I should only initialize connections after forking, but I don't  quite get why this is necessary when separate connections are used. Trying with `sqlalchemy` and `sqlite3` shows that this probably goes deeper than pw however.